# Select distinct records based on max(date) or NULL date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a list of employees based on their employee status or their most recent termination date.  If the employee is active, the termination date will be NULL.  There are also employees that have worked in multiple companies within our organization, I only want the record from the most recent company, whether active or terminated.  An employee may also have different Employee numbers in the different companies, so the selection will have to be based on the SSN (Fica) number.

Here is an original data set:

```
company employee    Fica    First_name  emp_status  Term_date
5       7026                Jason       T1          2013-09-16 00:00:00.000
500     7026                Jason       T1          2010-11-30 00:00:00.000
7       7026                Jason       T1          2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
2       90908               Jason       A1          NULL
505     293866              William     T1          2008-05-23 00:00:00.000
7       7243                Ashley      T1          2010-07-11 00:00:00.000
2       90478               Michael     T1          2013-01-11 00:00:00.000
500     90478               Michael     T1          2011-09-26 00:00:00.000
500     311002              Andreas     A1          NULL
3       365463              Matthew     A1          NULL
500     248766              Chris       T1          2007-04-23 00:00:00.000
500     90692               Kaitlyn     T1          2012-03-13 00:00:00.000
2       90692               Kaitlyn     A5          NULL
500     90236               Jeff        T1          2011-09-26 00:00:00.000
2       90236               Jeff        A1          NULL
2       90433               Nathan      T1          2012-03-26 00:00:00.000
500     90433               Nathan      T1          2011-09-26 00:00:00.000
```

Here are the results I am trying to get:

```
company employee    Fica    First_name  emp_status  Term_date
2       90908               Jason       A1          NULL
505     293866              William     T1          2008-05-23 00:00:00.000
7       7243                Ashley      T1          2010-07-11 00:00:00.000
2       90478               Michael     T1          2013-01-11 00:00:00.000
500     311002              Andreas     A1          NULL
3       365463              Matthew     A1          NULL
500     248766              Chris       T1          2007-04-23 00:00:00.000
2       90692               Kaitlyn     A5          NULL
2       90236               Jeff        A1          NULL
2       90433               Nathan      T1          2012-03-26 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks for any help you are able to give.  I need to run this on a SQL2005 server which will be connecting to an Oracle server via ODBC.

Comment: see the answer to "how to get the max row" on dba.stackexchange.com http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dates were all populated, you could do this with a "standard" `not exists` query.  The `NULL`s introduce a problem, but that problem can be solved using `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.employee = t.employee and
                        coalesce(t2.term_date, '9999-01-01') > coalesce(t.term_date, '9999-01-01)
                 );
```

NOTE:  If you need for this to work on Oracle, then you need a different format for the date constant.

EDIT:

Another way to solve this uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employee
                                order by (case when term_date is null then 0 else 1 end),
                                         term_date desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The rule for choosing the "last" row are embedded in the `order by` clause.  Put the `NULL` value first, followed by the `term_date` in descending order.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't aware that `row_number() over (partition by` was available in Oracle too...

Comment: I did not know the coalesce function would work with dates.  This retrieved the information the way I need it to.  Thank you.